# Java Problem with proper field initialization in an inheriting class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract base class called Entity. A certain method is called in the constructor of this class as in the following example:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    public Entity() {
        doSomething();
    }

    protected void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The Entity class is inherited by other classes. My problem is that inheriting classes that override a given method require access to certain fields of that class. Unfortunately, when the method is called, these fields are not initialized yet:

```
public class Player extends Entity {
    private final String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();

        System.out.println("Name: " + name); // <--- This isn't working properly
    }
}
```

In the example above, when "doSomething()" was called, the "name" field had not yet been assigned a value. Theoretically, you can call the method in any constructor of inheriting classes, but this raises some doubts. I am looking for a professional approach to solving this problem. I will be glad for help.

Answer (score 0):

Effective Java, one of the most widely recommended books on how to design good Java code, recommends the following "professional approach" in Item 19, on page 95 of its third edition:

> There are a few more restrictions that a class must obey to allow inheritance.
> **Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly.**

The implication from this is that there are three possibilities:

- Do not allow a class to be extended at all.
- Call no methods from its constructor.
- Call only `final` methods from its constructor.